# Magento Homepage Showing but other pages 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I tried installing an extension, and it said some core files where it wanted to install along where upgraded. I'm thinking it downgraded them so I upgraded again. I cleared the magento cache and now I'm getting a 500 error on every other page except the homepage.

Need help here. Any help is appreciated.

Using magento 1.9.

Comment: Name and version of the extension could be useful.

Comment: e-reactor Slider 1.0.0... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment, but for readability I post it as answer:

Release Date is 2013-08-09, so it is max. compatible with 1.7, but a comment on
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/e-reactor-slider.html

says that it also broke 1.7.0.2.

See installed files:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Ereactor_Slider/1.0.0/package.xml

Download-Link:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Ereactor_Slider/1.0.0/Ereactor_Slider-1.0.0.tgz

Releases (first and only release):
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Ereactor_Slider/releases.xml

So you could try to deactivate it in app/etc/modules/Ereactor_Slider.xml:

```
<active>false</active>
```

If that brings no success try to uninstall it and clear all caches again.

The developer is a company and has a shop for the extension with a contact form:

http://shop.e-reactor.dk/contacts/

Maybe they can help?

Good luck